# Getting "cannot convert double to float" error when using Math.Pow

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, exponential

I have the following:

```
        int val1 = 2;
        float val2 = (float)val1;

        decimal val3 = 3.2m;
        float val4 = (float)val3;

        float Result2 = Math.Pow(val4, val2);
```

It seems to me supposedly val4 and val2 are both in the float type. However i get a error on Math.Pow everytime signaling it can't convert type double to type float implicitly. I think i'm casting everything correctly, am I missing something?

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says: "can't convert [*double* -> *float*]". It can trivially reproduced: `double d = 1; float f = d;` So then find out which double expression is attempted to be used as a float. Now the problem is isolated a simple solution is present, as shown by R.T. Alternatively, use `double` over `float` everywhere and avoid the conversions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) takes two double arguments and *returns a double* - there is no implicit conversion from double to float. And  you cannot put the double in a float variable so you need to typecast that to float.

You may try this:

```
float Result2= (float)Math.Pow(val4, val2);
```

Comment: The floats are resolved to doubles without a problem, that's not the issue. It's that the resulting `double` cannot be placed inside the `float` variable.

Comment: So he takes doubles or floats in the val3 / val4, but the result has to be a double? That solved it, Thank you

Comment: @JeroenVannevel:- Indeed. Updated that in my answer. Thanks :)